# Regex without same characters next to eachother

Tags: regex

Hi i'm looking for a regex that uses three characters x, y, z that does not have 2 characters next to eachother that are the same.
for example:
xyx passes
xyzyzx passes
xyxxzy fails (two x's next to eachother)
xyxzxy passes
i tried "x(yz|yx)* | y(xz|xy)* | z(yz|yx)*" but that clearly isnt correct cause it doesn't include strings like xy or xyzxy. Please help me out

Comment: If this is homework, this means that you should have what it takes to solve it without external help. External help won't help you much anyway, because there's no way someone else than you knows what you've learned and hence, what's allowed or not.

Comment: Yea you're right, thank you for the hint though i got it

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead to do this.

`^(x(?!x)|y(?!y)|z(?!z))*$`

Edit: here's the general case:

`^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$`

Edit 2:

`^(x(?:[^x]|$)|y(?:[^y]|$)|z(?:[^z]|$))*$`

But seriously, do your own homework. You're learning *absolutely nothing* by copy and pasting my work.

Answer (score 0):

As this seems to be a homework, I won't disclose the full answer, but I will give you the full explanation using only basic regex (concatenation, Kleene star, and alternatives)

The idea is to split the language into three parts:

1. Those starting with `x`
2. Those starting with `y`
3. Those starting with `z`

Those cases are analogous to each other, so I will explain only one of them, say, the first one, those strings starting with `x`.

First, note that the language should only contain `y` and `z` between the two occurrences of `x`. Now we are considering strings that start with an `x`, so there must only be alternating `y` and `z` before the next `x`. So suppose `P` is a regex that matches "alternating `y` and `z` of length at least 1", we have the following regex to match this case:

```
x(Px)*P?
```

Because it will start with an `x`, then any number of repetition of `x`, each preceded with any sequence of alternating `y` and `z`, then it can optionally ends in another sequence of alternating `y` and `z` to cater all possible endings (`x`, `y`, and `z`)

Then what is `P`? Unsurprisingly, this is also of similar structure as we have just constructed, since the previous regex describes "alternating `x` and `P` of length at least 1 starting with `x`". So by changing `x` to `y` and `P` to `z`, and by considering those sequence starting with `y` and with `z`, we have `P` equals to:

```
y(zy)*z?|z(yz)*y?
```

And so you can replace `P` with that to get your full regex for case 1.

And we can do the same for case 2 and case 3, and you will have the full answer.

Note that following this method, you can extend the result to four variables and so on.